# using scanner how to calculate the no of character

Tags: java

Calculate the # of characters ***
What is your first name?: james
What is your middle name: hardy
What is your last name?: William

using scanner how to calculate the number of character.

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner sc = new Scabber(System.in);
```

`sc.nextLine().length()` will do it for you.

PS : you could also use `next()` if words are present in a single line and delimited by a space.

Comment: i try but it does not really work.could you please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(scanner.nextLine().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not explicitly required that you need to calculate the length using a scanner object, using `length()` will return the number of characters in any string.

** Using `scanner.nextLine().length()` is actually returning a string at the first method call, and then returning the length at the second method call anyway.